# how to get google translate for section with dropdown list of languages working?

Tags: google-translate

I'm trying to use google translate for translations of user comments. I'm using the official wizard (http://translate.google.com/translate_tools) to generate the java script and html code:

```
<script>
function googleSectionalElementInit() {
  new google.translate.SectionalElement({
    sectionalNodeClassName: 'goog-trans-section',
    controlNodeClassName: 'goog-trans-control',
    background: '#f4fa58'
  }, 'google_sectional_element');
}
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleSectionalElementInit&ug=section&hl=auto"></script>


<div class="goog-trans-section">
<div class="goog-trans-control">
</div>
some text in some language
</div>
```

I don't want the entire page to be translated, but only the comments. Unfortunately, the code generated for section translation doesn't come with a dropdown box for language selection. Does somebody know how to implement this? I tried to add `includedLanguages: 'en,fr,de,ru',` to the java script code, but it didn't help.

Comment: Did you ever figure this out? I've run into the same problem - trying to change from using the "entire webpage" snippet to using the "section of the webpage" snippet and now nothing happens...

Answer (score 8):

**The super simple thing is just use the steps below.**
1. add the following code where you want to show the translate dropdown.

```
<div id="google_translate_element"></div>
<script>
    function googleTranslateElementInit() {
      new google.translate.TranslateElement({
        pageLanguage: 'en'
      }, 'google_translate_element');
    }
</script>
<script src="//translate.google.com/translate_a/element.js?cb=googleTranslateElementInit"></script>
```

1. add class="notranslate" to body tag
2. add class="translate" to the section which you want to be translated by google translate.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the sectional translation widget behaves differently to how I was expecting (and maybe differently to how you were expecting too). The "entire webpage" widget gives you a dropdown and lets the user choose which language they want to display the page in.

The "section of the webpage" widget appears to be intended to deal with sites which have individual sections in different languages where you want the user to be able to translate those sections into your primary page language. This becomes clear when you click the "Preview your page" link on [the official wizard](http://translate.google.com/translate_tools).

If you look at the generated markup you will see that you mark up sections of the page something like this:

```
<div class="goog-trans-section" lang="zh-CN">
  ...content in Chinese...
</div>
```

The script then automatically appends a "Translate" link which allows you to translate this text back into English.

To achieve what I wanted (and what I guess you were trying to do too) I needed to stick to the "entire webpage" snippet but add a class of `notranslate` to anything that I didn't want to be translated.